# An idiomatic expression for: “not to be seen by someone”

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Sometimes I have something to share, but hope that it can't be seen by my close friends or family.

Is there a word, idiom , or a better expression that means: “not be seen by someone”

An example: (one or more words)

> I'd like to share this file but I don't want some of my friends to know, can it be  ________ ?

Comment: Could you provide a sentence and a blank space that shows how the word/expression would be used? For example: 1. "I would like to _______ this file"  Or 2. "Can I make this file ________?" Are you looking for a noun, verb or an adjective?

Comment: Sorry I removed SWR

Comment: Thanks for comments Mari. Is there no problem in the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is called a **secret**, as defined by [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secret):

> **secret** *noun*
>
> :  something kept from the knowledge of others or shared only confidentially with a few

Comment: Hi, macraf. I decided that it made no sense to reward Eli Kim for a plausible answer even though he didn't cite his sources, and yet not give you any credit for an equally valid answer that does cite its reference authority. +1.

Comment: @Rathony You think it should be accepted, I think it should contain the author of translation per [original comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336439/how-can-confession-mean-praise#comment772100_336439). You like half-baked work and voicing your infallibility. I think such behaviour is disgusting and this is my last response to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Confidential** (adjective  con·fi·den·tial  \ˌkän-fə-ˈden(t)-shəl)

1:  marked by intimacy or willingness to confide 
2:  private, secret 
3:  entrusted with confidences 
4:  containing information whose unauthorized disclosure could be prejudicial to the national interest — compare secret, top secret

ex) Can it be confidential?
ex) Can it be confidential between us?
ex) Can you keep it confidential?

<sub>[Definitions from [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidential).]</sub>

Comment: Hello, Eli Kim, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I upvoted your answer because I think the word you suggest is very suitable for the poster's needs. At this site, however, it's important to credit your sources; so please identify the reference work that your definitions came from, and provide a link to it if it is an online source. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, again, Eli Kim, I added the citation and link for you—but it's your responsibility to do so. Again, quoting a reference work without acknowledging the source is very poor practice, at EL&U and elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Sven Yargs, I haven't been on the website for a couple days, so sorry about the late reply, but thank you very much for notifying me. I appreciate it very much. As much as I have been learning a lot from this website, to contribute is a whole different matter, and your advice helps me greatly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> I'd like to share this file but I don't want some of my friends to know, can it be **[kept quiet](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+quiet)**?

The idiom "keep quiet" means:

> to refrain from talking about someone or something; to keep a secret about someone or something