# How can "confession" mean praise?

Tags: meaning

I was looking at a short summary of Augustine's Confessions, and came across a statement by the translator that though the word "confession" can mean acknowledgement of sin, it can also be a statement of praise.  Elsewhere, in religious writings, I also see it apparently meaning giving thanks, making a vow, etc.  Yet the dictionaries I looked at, don't have these meanings for confession.  They only mention confessing to one's sins or crimes or something that one finds shameful or embarrassing.  Confession's etymology apparently goes to "confiteri" which simply means to acknowledge.

Appreciate any help.

LATER EDIT:
I'll quote it from the book: "The very title itself can be read two ways: Of confession as praise, as well as confession as acknowledgement of faults." That's from the introduction, nothing more is said of that.

Comment: Please quote - and preferably link - the statement you mention.

Comment: [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confession) includes "confession of faith", as well as confession of crime or sin.

Comment: I don't have that summary right now but it's based on a a book that I have, so I can't link it.  It's entitled "Confessions", translated by Chadwick.  I'll quote it from the book:  "The very title itself can be read two ways: Of confession as praise, as well as confession as acknowledgement of faults."  Edit: that's from the introduction, nothing more is said of that.

Comment: [This site](http://emmanueldudleyministries.org/faith-confession-for-praise-and-worship/) refers to a "Faith Confession for Praise and Worship"

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, thanks Trevor.  Still odd that no dictionary I am looking at, mentions those meanings.  Unless confession meaning praise is strictly a religious meaning in context.  I mean I suppose I could tell someone, "I must confess you are beautiful" but still feels as if I'm admitting to something that is somehow embarrassing for me to be doing, it's not purely praise.

Comment: [Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=confession&title=21st) has (meaning 3) "a declaration of one's religious faith or principles • a confession of faith."

Comment: A confession does not mean praise- it means to divulge a secret that could be incriminating in some way. Or admitting something that you are hesitant to acknowledge. But the act of confession could be found worthy of praise.

Comment: The site mentioned above referring to "Faith Confession for Praise and Worship" goes on to state "Read the following confession several times each day to give praise and worship for God’s role in your life".  This links a *confession of faith* with "praising God".

Comment: Thanks guys for looking, looks like there is no clear answer, sometimes words take on additional meaning in certain contexts it seems.  I imagine if it's meaning, etymologically, is to merely acknowledge something, then it can mean quite a few things aside from admitting to guilt or sin or crime, which is often the case.  So it can also be including praise or acknowledging one's faith, in that religious context.  I can't be obsessing about this, maybe reading that summary will explain things better....

Comment: @AmirMord See my Answer below.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia, Confessions, St. Augustine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confessions_(Augustine)), first paragraph under the section Purpose.  You have to scroll quite far down.

Comment: Melville gives us a moving example of this usage in his essay on Hawthorne: "Give not over to future generations the glad duty of acknowledging him for what he is. Take that joy to yourself, in your own generation; and so shall he feel those grateful impulses in him, that may possibly prompt him to the full flower of some still greater achievement in your eyes. And by confessing him, you thereby confess others, you brace the whole brotherhood. For genius, all over the world, stands hand in hand, and one shock of recognition runs the whole circle round."

Answer (score 7):

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confession) gives one meaning of **confession** as:

> **confession of faith**
>   A statement setting out essential religious doctrine:
>   *a Protestant confession of faith*

[Chambers Dictionary](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=confession&title=21st) specifies one of the meanings of **confession** as

> a declaration of one's religious faith or principles • a confession of faith.

[This website](http://emmanueldudleyministries.org/faith-confession-for-praise-and-worship/) refers to:

> a "Faith Confession for Praise and Worship"

and states:

> "Read the following confession several times each day to give praise and worship …"

Your question refers to "*a statement by the translator that … the word 'confession' … can … **be** a statement of praise.*" and your quotation from the book actually states:

> "The very title itself can be read two ways: Of *confession as praise*, as well as confession as acknowledgement of faults."

Note that the quotation from the book did **not** actually state that *confession **means** praise* — rather that *confession [of faith] can **be** a "statement of praise"*.  That seems to me to be supported by the stated dictionary definitions and the usage examples given above.

Comment: In other words, 'confession' does not have a primary meaning (denotation) or secondary meaning (connotation) of praise, but is culturally associated, by implication, with the idea of praise in some religious contexts.

Comment: Whom is the confessor *praising?*

Comment: @Narasimham His/her god.